# How can I learn about writing project specs?

Tags: specifications, requirements

I recently read through Code Complete, and it recommends that I create a project specification before actually coding.

The book didn't go very far into detail about what 'specs' are, and how they are made. Because this is a crucial part of software development, I would like to know how to create quality specs that are not too exhaustive.

Where can I learn more about software specifications? Or any of the other prerequisites outlined in Code Complete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's Joel's article on Function Design documents.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html

Comment: @AndyMcKenna-Great minds think a like.  +1

Comment: I'm a developer in our Marketing department, that article was crucial in explaining to my bosses that you can't just whip up entire applications without any prior thought.

Comment: #1 quote from that article: "The moral of the story is that with a contrived example, you can prove anything." Haha -- But really a great article. +1

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for books, I can recommend two right now, and in fact, I ordered a third because it looked good.

The two I can recommend fully are:

- [Software Requirements (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735618798)
- [More about Software Requirements](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622671)

I also ordered a third book:

- [Software Requirements Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623988)

Answer (score 2):

Joel Spolsky posted the functional spec to his CoPilot application along with a brief blog post about it.
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/AardvarkSpec.html